# Symfony2 security session ending and no redirection

Tags: security, symfony

I have a problem in my Symfony2 project. Sometimes, when I'm logged in, I get disconnected on random intervals of time, sometimes 2 hours, sometimes 2 minutes later.

But the real problem is that I'm not redirected to my login form. I'm displaying the name of the logged user in my layout file, and get this error :

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("member") on a string variable ("anon.") in AppBundle:Layout:top_menu.html.twig at line 25
```

when I get a wild forced logout.

Here is my security.yml file

```
security:
providers:
    insiders:
        entity:
            class: Interne\SecurityBundle\Entity\User
            property: username

encoders:
    Interne\SecurityBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

firewalls:

    interne:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /interne

        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /login


access_control:
    - { path: ^/interne, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
```

Any help would be really appreciated ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

use this in your top_menu:

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
    <p>Username: {{ app.user.username }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object

Comment: That's not the problem. I want to know why I'm being disconnected and why the system doesnt redirect me to my login form as it should do.

Comment: why should it your firewall pattern is for /.